# How do get this database cloud function to fire?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

**UPDATE**

The challenging database function works when deployed but not with the emulator

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have a couple of http cloud functions and one database cloud function in my cloud functions project.
All http cloud functions are running fine but the database cloud function is never triggered irrespective of the many fixes I've made.

When I start the cloud functions emulator, I see the database cloud function alongside the http functions on the list of functions being initialised, but the database cloud function is never triggered whenever new modifications are made to the database path (`potential-students`) that it is supposed to monitor.

Here are snippets of my `index.js` code

```js
// This cloud function works perfectly
exports.status = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, resp) => {
  console.log("Hitting /status with", req.hostname, req.baseUrl, req.path);
  return resp.status(200).send({
    ok: true,
    data: {
      message:
        "connected to HTTP Cloud Function listener"
    }
  });
});
```

Here are different versions of the database function I've tried

```js
exports.notifyOnPreRegistration = functions.database
  .ref("/potential-students")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    console.log("running");
    console.log(change);
    console.log(context);
  });
```

```js
exports.notifyOnPreRegistration = functions.database
  .ref("potential-students")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    console.log("running");
    console.log(change);
    console.log(context);
  });
```

Whenever I try to access `localhost:9000/potential-students.json`, I get `null` as the response.
I also see this in my `database.debug.log` file

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/path/firebase/emulators/firebase-database-emulator-v4.3.1.jar) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
12:38:29.482 [NamespaceSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
12:38:29.627 [main] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Listening at localhost:9000
```

Below is a picture of my terminal when I run my emulator. I'll be glad to provide any other non-secret information if required.
[image]

My question is: How do get this database cloud function to fire?

Comment: Would you recommend file an issue on this on Github?

Answer (score 0):

I get it you need to fire the database function everytime a document is created, modified or deleted, right? If so, this should work:

```
exports.notifyOnPreRegistration = functions.database
  .ref("/potential-students/{studentId}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    console.log("running");
    console.log(change);
    console.log(context);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but it doesn't work :( The docs say it'll fire at changes on the monitored path and any nested path in the monitored path